# How to run several functions with different time interval in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, serial-communication

I am trying to use python to request for data from a flight control board using serial communication.

There are several fields of data, but wish to update with different rate. For example, field A will get updated every 0.001s, field B will get updated every 0.02s, field C every 1s.

As there might be packet loss, so sometimes it may take longer to read data and time.sleep() will cause inaccurate time interval. Also the class doing the serial communication is not thread safe, so any method which may cause thread safe problem cannot be used.

Following is the main structure of the process, is there anything I can do to make it request for data with the time interval I wish?

```
class WorkerProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, port, addresslist, task_queue, result_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.exit = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.serialPort = port
        self.addressList = addresslist
        self.sch = SerialCommunication(self.serialPort, self.addressList)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self.modeSelection = 0

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit.is_set():
            ...
            self.sch.requestA()
            self.sch.requestB()
            self.sch.requestC()
            ...

    def shutdown(self):
        print("Shutdown initiated")
        try:
            self.sch.stopSerial()
        except Exception:
            print(Exception)
        print('Process stopped')
        self.exit.set()
```

Comment: You can try to use Queue to manage the call stack. And put call's in it with three different Timer (from threading package). But it seems not very good. Maybe you can manage the code from hardware and send series as one object? (because of calls are sync) Or ask last amount of data like get_a(len_a). All fields from the same bus?

Comment: @gelezko Well, I think using Timer to put tasks into Queue looks good, may not elegant, but should work. I will test it. The other one may not work for my case since I am using wireless communication, packet loss is very serious and I am trying to reduce data amount. That is why I use different time interval: to reduce data as much as possible.

Comment: The communication process is: device 1: request field A; device 2: after receiving command, send out data of field A; device 1: receive field A. The hardware (device 2) will only send out data passively with request. Also it is a little complex to change the code on hardware.

Comment: With queue based implementation, you must ensure that the device will be able to process all requests to avoid delays. Another solution is using predefined loop, which divided to 3 steps(in this case). Each step contain requests to specific service, and check the execution time. Using wireless connection you can check the signal strength to predict the loss.

Comment: @gelezko Yes, you are right. I have been suffering packet loss situation. It is really a pain. I will check the others. Thanks.